# Shift register with initial value 1

Tags: led, shift-register

I would like to have a circuit with 8 LED outputs and one input - clk.

On each clk edge output should be like this:

1. 0000 0001
2. 0000 0010
3. 0000 0100
4. 0000 1000
5. 0001 0000
6. 0010 0000
7. 0100 0000
8. 1000 0000

How to move by one is clear for me. But how to start with value 1 in the register? Or there is other solution without shift register?

Comment: use a 4017 counter (1 out of 10) and reset  at count 8

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user is asking for design, presented no research, and hasn't tried anything.

Comment: [Ring counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter)

Comment: BTW a 4017 **is** a ring counter http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-jYE6bUAaWLQ/TpaMzxeGuiI/AAAAAAAABBY/ElJW2MjJvu4/s1600/function+diagram+of+4017.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some shift registers allow a parallel load. If so, you can just wire up your default case and at power-on reset cause a load to take place. Or you can use the *set* input of the first FF, I suppose.

But a Johnson counter with decoding is what's often done. You can look at the  CD4022B, for an example. The schematic also includes a so-called "disallowed state detector" made out of an AND and NOR gate, as well.